# Every positive formula is satisifiable

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> We say that a propositional logical formula is positive if it does not
>   include the negation connective ¬ anywhere in it (but it may still use
>   ∧, ∨, ↔, →, and propositions). Show that all positive formulas are
>   satisfiable formulas.

Any tips/ideas how I can show that?

Comment: Try by induction on the construction of formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Note*: This procedure assumes you are referring to a propositional language $$L_V=\left<V,\rightarrow,\bot \right>$$ where $V$ is the set of proposition symbols of $L_V$. $L_\Sigma^*$ denotes the set of all strings of $L_V$.

**Hint:**

We are going to define the set of positive formulas of $L_V$, call it $POS_{L_V}$:

> **Definition**: *The set POS of positive well-formed formulas of $L_V$ is the set satisfying*
>
> 1. $\alpha \in POS$ *if* $\alpha \in V$
> 2. $(\alpha \rightarrow \beta) \in PROP$ *if* $\alpha, \beta \in POS$
> 3. *No string that is not obtained by (1) or (2) belongs to* *POS*.

Now it is easier to put the statement we want to prove:

> $$\phi \in POS \Rightarrow M \vDash \phi$$

For some interpretation $M$.

So is it easier to proceed now? What about a induction on the structure of *POS*?